# Transforming collections with animation nodes

Tags: animation-nodes, collections

Hello everyone and happy holidays! So I really would love to parent a collection to an empty since instancing can be so messy but what I had not considered is ... perhaps using animation nodes to transform a collection ...

So I am just curious if I could use animation nodes to move my collections around ?

Comment: Yes you can, what exactly is giving you trouble here ? Can you post an example of what you have tried ? Please give as much detail as possible :)

Comment: awesome! .... well, I am VERY green to animation nodes so .... I have just been reading and switching buttons, but nothing is working right ... so I am pretty much at square one

Comment: Check out this Tutorial Series for basic concepts. Its worth it, animation nodes is a great tool: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgiVhvYU2mk&list=PLJSCK4DjIWhk-JIGOIJKLUB1bGXfDBgzZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case A** (blue) would be to set the parent parameter every object has, wich also can be found in *Object Properties > Relations > Parent*
For a onetime operation this could also be done via shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or python.

**Case B** (green) does not parent but moves a collection of objects in realtion to another. Here the logic of animation nodes and its potential maybe is more apparent.
Important: for this to work you have to check *Delta Transforms* in *Object Transform Output > N-Panel > Item > Advanced Node Settings > Delta Transforms*.

[image]

Here you can see were to find the *Delta Transform* toggle in the *Object Transform Output* Node:
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks AM , I tried this setup since it looks like it makes sense but I could not get it to work in Blender. I have the exact same setup as you, node for node, but I could not find the delta transforms option in the drop down. 

All my test object just smashed together at the center of the world ... not sure what to do next

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Hope it helps :)